# What location does URL url = getClass().getResource("") refer to?

Tags: java, swing, url, classpath, awt

In Java program when we do

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("res/Radiobox_Selected.jpg");
```

What location does it refers to? Is it Project root location or package location?

I have pasted image in all possible locations, but I am still getting following exception:

```
Uncaught error fetching image: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getDecoder(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I think that nothing better around as an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788331/once-exported-java-cannot-find-draw-images/7788426#7788426 by @Hovercraft Full Of Eels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It refers to the location related all the packages in your current CLASSPATH.