# Error with image resources in jar file

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm having a problem with running a jar file. If I compile the code in eclipse everything is ok, but when I export to jar and try to run the program it throws an error.
The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at game.ChessSquare.<init>(ChessSquare.java:17)
    at game.ChessFrame.DrawField(ChessFrame.java:131)
    at game.ChessFrame.<init>(ChessFrame.java:38)
    at game.Chess.main(Chess.java:7)
```

So the piece of code that throws this error is

```
//text is something like "pawn" or "king".The whole image is an icon on the button 
img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("white/"+text+".png"));
```

As I understand, it can't find the image so img variable is null. But I can't understand why then it does run in eclipse. Any help with this? Thanks

P.S @AndrewThompson

```
E:\Desktop>jar tvf chess.jar
49 Sat Feb 11 23:40:06 GMT 2012 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
378 Sat Feb 11 22:51:04 GMT 2012 game/ChessFieldCoord.class
1932 Sat Feb 11 23:39:48 GMT 2012 game/ChessSquare.class
536 Sat Feb 11 22:51:04 GMT 2012 game/Chess.class
2122 Sat Feb 11 22:51:04 GMT 2012 game/Rook.class
2357 Sat Feb 11 22:51:04 GMT 2012 game/Bishop.class
1946 Sat Feb 11 22:51:04 GMT 2012 game/Queen.class
2127 Sat Feb 11 22:51:04 GMT 2012 game/Pawn.class
1630 Sat Feb 11 22:51:04 GMT 2012 game/Knight.class
878 Sat Feb 11 22:51:04 GMT 2012 game/Empty.class
1642 Sat Feb 11 22:51:04 GMT 2012 game/King.class
915 Sat Feb 11 22:52:32 GMT 2012 game/ChessFrame$1.class
841 Sat Feb 11 22:52:32 GMT 2012 game/ChessFrame$2.class
695 Sat Feb 11 22:52:32 GMT 2012 game/ChessFrame$3.class
3525 Sat Feb 11 22:52:32 GMT 2012 game/ChessFrame$Move.class
4675 Sat Feb 11 22:52:32 GMT 2012 game/ChessFrame.class
997 Sat Feb 11 22:51:04 GMT 2012 game/ChessFigure.class
928 Sat Feb 11 15:49:32 GMT 2012 game/black/bishop.png
1947 Sat Feb 11 15:49:10 GMT 2012 game/black/king.png
1247 Sat Feb 11 15:49:38 GMT 2012 game/black/knight.png
627 Sat Feb 11 15:49:44 GMT 2012 game/black/pawn.png
1668 Sat Feb 11 15:49:20 GMT 2012 game/black/queen.png
626 Sat Feb 11 15:49:26 GMT 2012 game/black/rook.png
1493 Sat Feb 11 15:48:30 GMT 2012 game/white/bishop.png
1889 Sat Feb 11 15:48:06 GMT 2012 game/white/king.png
1544 Sat Feb 11 15:48:40 GMT 2012 game/white/knight.png
1003 Sat Feb 11 15:48:48 GMT 2012 game/white/pawn.png
2440 Sat Feb 11 15:48:12 GMT 2012 game/white/queen.png
837 Sat Feb 11 15:48:20 GMT 2012 game/white/rook.png
```

The file where the error occurs is ChessSquare.class

Comment: Have you checked what is in the final Jar?

Comment: Check for file "white/XXX.png" in your .jar file.  FYI, you can view/edit your jar file with the standard "winzip" command (as well as the JDK "jar" command line tool).

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wPyuO.png - this is chess.jar inside. The thing i can't understand is why it runs from eclipse and not from jar. The folder structure is always the same :(

Comment: Because it's in game/white, not white?

Comment: 1) To notify someone that you made a comment, prefix the comment with @PersonName 2) Please don't post screenshots of textual information.  Use the [`jar` tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html) to list the contents in the command line (see **List table of contents of jar file**), then copy/paste the output.

Comment: @DaveNewton if i write img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("game/white/"+text+".png")); it doesn't even compile saying that images cannot be found. Changing to "/game/..." doesn't work either

Comment: What does the project structure look like within Eclipse?  Are these images part of the same tree as the java sources or in a different directory?

Comment: @wort In eclipse they are in the different directories

Comment: If you print the URL returned by getResource(), what does it print?

Comment: If you got a compile error changing a during path in the code then you likely did something else wrong.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788331/once-exported-java-cannot-find-draw-images

Comment: @eee if the code is `img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/game/white/"+text+".png"));` the URL it returns when i compile it in eclipse is `"file:/E:/Desktop/Chess/bin/game/white/Pawn.png"`

Comment: Also I have exactly the same structure as in the Edit 1 section on the link you gave, I rewrote the code as the Hovercraft Full Of Eels recommends but it still throws the execeptions and they seem to be fatal.

Comment: @makey Without knowing how your Eclipse is configured, how you're creating the jar, etc. it's impossible to answer why it works in Eclipse. You should configure your Eclipse so it behaves the same way as when you run it from the jar.

Comment: @makey the file URI doesn't look right to me...it should be `"file:///E:/Desktop/Chess/bin/game/white/Pawn.png"` ...I mean the `"file://"` see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.4. But, this is strange since it shall refer to the classpath of the jar

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comments, look in your jar (use winzip, 7zip, or something like that) to see where the resource is located.  If it is not in a "white" directory then something is wrong with your jar build.

As to why it's running in Eclipse... that's likely because Eclipse is including the resource directory in the classpath when you run the program.  This means that the getClass().getResource(...) call finds the png.

If you are keeping the file in a resources directory in Eclipse it also could be exporting the files into the META-INF directory in the jar, look in resources.  If it is doing that then you may have setup the jar to be built for deployment into a web environment (see servlet 3.0 fragments).

One final note, be careful about using getClass().getResource(...) as it locks you down to only finding resources associated with the ClassLoader of the Class making that call (subject to how the ClassLoader hierarchy in question operates).  You may want to provide extensions later where you can package other image sets in jars.  In those cases you'll have to rely on slightly different mechanisms to get the images loaded (see ClassLoader.getResources as a starting point).

EDIT: This looks to be strictly an Eclipse problem.  According to the way that the jar is structured the correct path is "game/white/king.png".

Comment: I also tried exporting to jar with BlueJ, same thing, it runs from the IDE but not from the jar. I'm new to Java but its behaviour seems very strange to me

Comment: Right click on the resource folder containing the images and check the properties (also do this looking at the build properties for your project).  What you are looking for is something that indicates what directory the resources are being copied to.  If you were doing this with Ant or a similar tool you would either copy the resources into the classes directory then jar the classes directory or add them after the fact with the zip ant task.

Answer (score 0):

```
img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/game/white/"+text+".png"));
```

Note the leading slash, as well as the `game` prefix.

Comment: As already told to DaveNewton it doesn't work. Same error when I try to run it. Without the leading slash it doesn't even compile. Before posting here I already tried every possible combination of addresses :(

Comment: *"tried **every** possible combination of addresses"* Obviously not, since **one of them will work.**  Also, it should have compiled OK with or without the `/`.  The leading `/` simply means 'look from the root of the class-path'.  Without the `/`, it would be searching from the package of the class file.

Answer (score 0):

i'm an idiot, i finally figured out where the error was. As I wrote the output was `"file:/E:/Desktop/Chess/bin/game/white/Pawn.png"`, notice the big P letter in Pawn.png. But the actual images' names started with small letters. That's why it didn't work. Still a mystery for me why then it worked in eclipse