# Why does this "new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("files/icon.png")).getImage();" make my Program invisible?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, executable, invisible

I wrote this

```
 Image icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("files/icon.png")).getImage();
```

in a JFrame-extending class to then set the icon of the frame with

```
this.setIconImage(icon);
```

I do it this way, intead of by simply using the Path, because otherwise the Icon would disappear, if I exported my Project as an executable .jar. (as seen here: [Once exported, java cannot find/draw images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788331/once-exported-java-cannot-find-draw-images))

The problem that occurs now is, that the executable .jar works the way it should (It creates a folder, as well as a .xml-file and writes into it), but without generating a visible frame.
If I run the program in eclipse however, everything works fine and I see the frame.
I found out, that the problem has to be in the creation of an ImageIcon, because if I run

```
getClass().getResource("files/icon.png");
```

everything works fine.
The file is at it's place, too, so this shouldn't be the mistake.

Hope you can help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: the path you are using is relative or absolute?

Comment: It's possible that it's throwing a `NullPointerException` because the images haven't be exported along with the Jar

Comment: @Blip relative to the class i call the method in (RTFrame, http://epvpimg.com/kOCDg) ,@MadProgrammer the image can be found in the exported file under the right path so I don't think so :/

Comment: So, add traces in the code. Print the value of `getClass()`. Print the value of `getClass().getResource("files/icon.png")`. Print the value of `new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("files/icon.png"))`. Look for exception stack traces in the console. See what `jar tvf yourjar.jar` gives. Usual debugging stuff. We can't help if all you're saying to us is that the frame doesn't appear, and that you don't believe that what we suspect is true. Prove us wrong.

Comment: @JBNizet I should've thought of this earlier... sorry. The results: http://pastebin.com/gSBwinby The problem now obviously is the Resource, I get with ".getResource", because its null. Unfortunately I don't have a clue how to fix that! Thanks anyways for the great help until now!

Comment: So, either the file is not in the jar, or there is some case-sensitivity problem. What's the output of `jar tvf yourjar.jar`?

Comment: I disagree with @Coffee about deleting the answer.  Sometimes the perfect answer is short!  If you re-instate the answer you can accept it and 'finish' this Q&A (and if you let me know, I might up-vote the answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys, it was all my fault...
@JBNizet you had the right clue again... it was the case of the path "files/icon.png" -> "Files/icon.png"

Comment: Not sure why you answered here , then. a comment would suffice if the answer's this brief